# Seaborn kernel density estimate but with values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to make an heatmap using seaborn.

My dataset looks like this:

```
start_x | end_x 
1           3
3           4
7           5
9           6
```

I was able to do an heatmap using `seaborn.kde` method and the results are what I was expecting

[image]

However, I would like to know how would I do the exact same thing but instead of using the density, I would use the value of each x, y point.

```
start_x | end_x | value
1           3       1
3           4       1.5
7           5       1.2
9           6       1.7
```

Is there any similar function to kde that does this in seaborn? Is there any other good approach?

Kind regards

EDIT:

I used the KDE function with weights and this is the result:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)
sns.kdeplot(x_coords, y_coords, shade = True, color = 'red', n_levels = 10, \
            weights=weights)
```

[image]

Versus without:

[image]

I don't think it is making much of an impact, even with `bw=0.5` as suggested by @JohanC.

Created a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wV0aAzrc) with my x/y coords and weights

Comment: Please post the full code for your example plot, preferably together with some toy data.     Did you try something like `sns.kdeplot(x=df['start_x'], y=df['end_x'], weights=df['value'], ...)`?

Comment: I tried that but I think that if the density is too high in one spot it overcomes the weights. It is just an assumption though

Comment: Well, usually the weights work well. Could you provide some toy data of an example where it doesn't work as expected?  Without data and example code, it will be very hard to answer your question.

Comment: Maybe the default bandwidth calculation doesn't work well in your case (especially with few points). In the latest Seaborn (0.11), try to set an adjustment: `sns.kdeplot(x=df['start_x'], y=df['end_x'], weights=df['value'], cmap='Reds', shade=True, bw_adjust=0.5)`

Comment: @JohanC updated my question with an example and the data necessary to run it. Can you check it please? Also is it possible to set a low threshold so the 0 values become transparent? Thanks!